# Parse string to avro schema

Tags: java, testing, avro

I have an auto-generated avro schema java class

```
public class Event extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase implements org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord {
...
}
```

In my test file, I have a sample string:

```
private static final String EVENT = "{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"test\", \"date_created\": 1476644746, \"date_updated\": \"1476644746\", \"content_type\": \"string\", \"content\": \"test\"}"
```

If my `Event` was a simple Object, I could initialize it as:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Event event = mapper.readValues(EVENT, Event.class);
```

But this does not work when I have an avro schema. How do I parse this string into an `Event` so I can test against it?